# MEF load dependencies of host application

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I currently build an MEF application which contains a host application and some plugins (dlls). The plugins are getting dynamically loaded from folders and are able to export views and classes. Each plugin should use methods from a huge framework. The framework itself reads some important data (like logging configuration) from the App.config. Because it needs the App.config file I added the references to these parts of the framework in the main application and implemented the configuration. From now on I will call those parts of the framework *core dependencies*.

When a plugin wants to use other parts of the framework the *core dependencies* need to be implemented. Because I can not reference them in each plugin I'm getting an `System.TypeInitializationException` exception. The plugins are not able to read the core dependencies of the host application.

Is it possible to tranfer the references of my host application to each plugin?

### EDIT:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2QlM.png) are two references I need to include in my plugin. [These](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE0NI.png) are my core dependencies for the whole project. The problem is that those plugin references depend on the core dependencies. Because of this, the plugin includes the core dependencies by itself but does not contain any configuration for it. The error is the following:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' in System.Configuration.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in xxx.xxx.Logging.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.DataAccess.dll
```

The exception is thrown because there is no configuration to read from.
I need the plugin to use the core dependencies referenced in the host application isteead of including its own. My question is if MEF provides an mechanism to export the dependencies to another dll or somehow work arround my issue.

Comment: Do you have code example, are you using imports?

Comment: Too hard to answer without code. It's not clear, how reading app.config from somewhere affects host app references. Also, it would be great to see full exception text.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully you now understand what I mean.